# Javascript to open new ASP.NET website (page.aspx) and pass a value to its textbox

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Lets suppose I have a `ASP.NET` website `page.aspx` with one `textbox` (`tb_userName`) I need a `javascript` that opens `page.aspx` and pass a vale to `textbox` (`tb_userName`). I am trying this code and I am having no success.

I simply want to open `page.aspx` and string value passed to `tb_userName`

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, typeof(Page), 
   "OpenWindow", "window.open('http://localhost/Web01/page.aspx?
         tb_userName=" + someOne.ToString() + "');",true);
```

Comment: are you the script owner of the 'page.aspx'

Comment: do you want to pass `textbox` value in URL ?

Comment: Setting a value in the querystring will do nothing if the page is not set up to handle that.

Comment: "Setting a value in the querystring will do nothing if the page is not set up to handle that." I donot have any idea what you mean thnks.